# Issue regarding web socket in socket.io (back-end placed in different folder)

Tags: websocket, socket.io, easyrtc, aframe-networked

I am using express js, socket.io, and easyRtc for my back-end. I've to connect the back-end with client-side code. And we are hitting
http://localhost:3333/quagmire-api/ to connect with the server-side. All the other requests are coming fine rather than
[image]

this web socket url.

[image: error which is coming]
This error is coming when we are using http://localhost:3333/quagmire-api/ this url. But when we are using http://localhost:3333/ this url (means when the server is running without /quagmire-api/) it working fine.
[image: working example]
This is working here.

**Help me with this. How can i resolve this?**